# Get controller name in TWIG template

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

I am learning symfony2.3, and I am getting an error when I try to get controller name in twig template.

Controller:

```
namespace Acme\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('AcmeAdminBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }
}
```

In my TWIG template:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
 {{ app.request.get('_template').get('controller') }}
 Hello {{ name }}!!!
{% endblock %}
```

Output:

```
Impossible to invoke a method ("get") on a NULL variable ("") in AcmeAdminBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 3
```

I want output as "Default"

I am using symfony 2.3, I have also tried on symfony 2.1 but on both version generates the same error.

Comment: But, why do you need this information?

Comment: I want to add class to some links basis on controller name.

Answer (score 33):

use this line to display a controller name in twig:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get("_controller") }}
```

Comment: tnx!! `{{ app.request.attributes.get("_route") }}` for route name.

Comment: I wonder why this isn't the accepted & most voted answer, easy & clean built-in, what's the matter ?!

Comment: you need to use it inside a JS block like this: `{% block javascripts %}{{app.req....}}{% endblock %}`

Answer (score 17):

Many months ago I had the same problem as you, and "googling" I found a working code and I had adapted it to my necessities. Here we go:

**1 -** We need to define a TWIG extension for that. We create the folder structure *Your\OwnBundle\Twig\Extension* if you haven't defined yet.

**2 -** Inside this folder we create the file *ControllerActionExtension.php* which code is:

```
namespace Your\OwnBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * A TWIG Extension which allows to show Controller and Action name in a TWIG view.
 * 
 * The Controller/Action name will be shown in lowercase. For example: 'default' or 'index'
 * 
 */
class ControllerActionExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var Request 
     */
    protected $request;

   /**
    * @var \Twig_Environment
    */
    protected $environment;

    public function setRequest(Request $request = null)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function initRuntime(\Twig_Environment $environment)
    {
        $this->environment = $environment;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            'get_controller_name' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getControllerName'),
            'get_action_name' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'getActionName'),
        );
    }

    /**
    * Get current controller name
    */
    public function getControllerName()
    {
        if(null !== $this->request)
        {
            $pattern = "#Controller\\\([a-zA-Z]*)Controller#";
            $matches = array();
            preg_match($pattern, $this->request->get('_controller'), $matches);

            return strtolower($matches[1]);
        }

    }

    /**
    * Get current action name
    */
    public function getActionName()
    {
        if(null !== $this->request)
        {
            $pattern = "#::([a-zA-Z]*)Action#";
            $matches = array();
            preg_match($pattern, $this->request->get('_controller'), $matches);

            return $matches[1];
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'your_own_controller_action_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

**3 -** After that we need to specify the service for TWIG to be recognized:

```
services:
    your.own.twig.controller_action_extension:
        class: Your\OwnBundle\Twig\Extension\ControllerActionExtension
        calls:
            - [setRequest, ["@?request="]]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

**4 -** Cache clear to make sure everything is ok:

```
php app/console cache:clear --no-warmup
```

**5 -** And now, if I'm not forgetting anything, you will be able to access those 2 methods in a TWIG template: `get_controller_name()` and `get_action_name()`

**6 -** Examples:

```
You are in the {{ get_action_name() }} action of the {{ get_controller_name() }} controller.
```

This will output something like: *You are in the index action of the default controller.*

You can also use to check:

```
{% if get_controller_name() == 'default' %}
Whatever
{% else %}
Blablabla
{% endif %}
```

And that's all!! I hope I helped you, mate :)

**Edit:** Take care about the clearing cache. If you don't use `--no-warmup` parameter maybe you will realize that nothing is shown in your templates. That's because this TWIG Extension uses the Request to extract the Controller and Action names. If you "warm up" the cache, the Request is not the same as a browser request, and the methods can return `''` or `null`

Comment: I need get the controller class from a custom twig extension, using your solution always i get `You have requested a non-existent service "sensio_distribution.webconfigurator"`

Comment: Sure, the extension is working now, but i need add a new function and in this funcion i need use the Request

Comment: My answer is for Symfony 2.3, since 2.4 the request in many cases is handled in a different way: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack I hope it will help you. If it doesn't, ask again (or open a question for us to see your whole code and the goal you want to reach)

Comment: thanks Dani, using the documentation i found i need use scope (i'm using symfony 2.4). i resolve the problem with a synthetic service :)

Answer (score 6):

Since Symfony 3.x, service request is replaced by request_stack, and Twig Extension declaration changed since Twig 1.12.

I will correct the answer of Dani (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17544023/3665477) :

**1 -** We need to define a TWIG extension for that. We create the folder structure *AppBundle\Twig\Extension* if you haven't defined yet.

**2 -** Inside this folder we create the file *ControllerActionExtension.php* which code is:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class ControllerActionExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /** @var RequestStack */
    protected $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getControllerName', [$this, 'getControllerName']),
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getActionName', [$this, 'getActionName'])
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get current controller name
     *
     * @return string
    */
    public function getControllerName()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        if (null !== $request) {
            $pattern = "#Controller\\\([a-zA-Z]*)Controller#";
            $matches = [];
            preg_match($pattern, $request->get('_controller'), $matches);

            return strtolower($matches[1]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get current action name
     *
     * @return string
    */
    public function getActionName()
    {
        $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        if (null !== $request) {
            $pattern = "#::([a-zA-Z]*)Action#";
            $matches = [];
            preg_match($pattern, $request->get('_controller'), $matches);

            return $matches[1];
        }
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'controller_action_twig_extension';
    }
}
```

**3 -** After that we need to specify the service for TWIG to be recognized:

```
app.twig.controller_action_extension:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\Extension\ControllerActionExtension
    arguments: [ '@request_stack' ]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

**4 -** Cache clear to make sure everything is ok:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup
```

**5 -** And now, if I'm not forgetting anything, you will be able to access those 2 methods in a TWIG template: *getControllerName()* and *getActionName()*

**6 -** Examples:

You are in the {{ getActionName() }} action of the {{ getControllerName() }} controller.

This will output something like: You are in the index action of the default controller.

You can also use to check:

```
{% if getControllerName() == 'default' %}
Whatever
{% else %}
Blablabla
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see WHY you would need this.
You might better send parameters into your view.

But if you really need it this way, here's a solution:

Your error comes from the second `get` method

```
request = app.request              // Request object
NULL    = request.get('_template') // Undefined attribute, default NULL
NULL.get('controller')             // Triggers error
```

If you want to get the controller called during the request you can access it via the key `_controller` of the request **attribute**

```
app.request.attribute.get('_controller')
```

Will return

```
Acme\AdminBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction
```

You can then parse it the way you want.

*Note that this won't return the controller instance, only its name and method called*

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my question
but if there is inbuilt functionality in symfony then I should use that insteade of parsing string
see link I found over web http://ostedesign.com/get-controller-name-inside-symfony2-twig-template

Comment: The code in your link is wrong. But no, you cannot get the **shortname** (- Controller) of the controller class from a built-in Twig variable. The `app` variable is a `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\GlobalVariables` instance which does not expose its container

Answer (score 0):

To get the controller - {{ app.request.attributes.get('_controller') }}
To get the Action - {{ app.request.attributes.get('_template').get('name') }}

Found at  - http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=34083

Answer (score 0):

It can vary. If you're using annotations in the controller, e.g. `@Template("AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index")`, trying to access `app.request.get('_template')` in your Twig template will return a string e.g. "AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index". So you might need to access it like this:

```
{% set _template = app.request.get('_template')|split(':') %}
{% set controller = _template[1] %}
{% set bundle = _template[0] %}
```

If you're not using annotations then you can use the `app.request.get('_template').get('_controller')`

Answer (score -1):

Controller:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_template').get('controller') }}
```

Action:

```
{{ app.request.attributes.get('_template').get('name') }}
```

enjoy ;)