# Symfony2: Routing annotation as group?

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

I have a annotation like this:

```
 /**
 * @Route(name="landingpage_test_1", path="/test/{type}/{name}-t{testCode1}.html"})
 * @Route(name="landingpage_test_2", path="/test/{type}/{name}-t{testCode1}t{testCode2}.html"})
 * @Route(name="landingpage_test_3", path="/test/{type}/{name}-t{testCode1}t{testCode2}t{testCode3}.html"})
 * @Template()
 * @Cache(smaxage=3600)
 */
```

In my twig-template I have an if-clause where I have to check, if a specific controller is called. When there is only one name, its no problem to handle this:

```
app.request.get('_route')
```

Bute in my case, I have 3 route-names.

Is it possible to make all 3 route names in a group? Like:

```
... @Route(name="landingpage_test_1", group="landingpage", path="/test/{type}/{name}-t{testCode1}.html"}) ....
```

Comment: Don't know if you can group them and don't know if this choice could lead you to a solution. BTW you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234249/get-controller-name-in-twig-template

Answer (score 0):

`app.request.get('_route')` will contain the value of the current matched route, so only one value.

If you want to match the 3 routes in your template, you should change your `if` statement to be something like `{% if app.request.get('_route') starts with 'landingpage_test_' %}`